# Format number(money) from mysql

Tags: mysql, formatting, decimal

Currently I have: 150000.52 Euros 
I would like to have: 150.000,52 Euro

I tried format, cast , and convert and didn't work .
Thanks for coming here to try to help .

Comment: Hmm, I'd like 150,000 euros too ;). The function you are looking for is `format()` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_format).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this use MySQL `FORMAT` :-

```
concat(FORMAT('150000.52',2,'de_DE'),' Euro')
```